# How to initialize a class object?

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I have these 2 specific classes:

```
class foo{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    foo(int x, int y)
    :a(x), b(y)
    {
        cout << "I just created a foo! << endl;
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        cout << "A foo was just destroyed!" << endl;
    }

    void set_a(int a_num)
    {
        a = a_num;
    }

    void set_b(int b_num)
    {
        b = b_num;
    }

class bar{
private:
    int T;
    int S;
    foo f;
public:
    bar(int x, int y, foo n=(0,0) <--
    :T(x), S(y), f(n)
    {
        cout << "I just created a f!" << endl;
        foo.set_a(T); <--
        foo.set_b(S); <--

    }

    ~bar(){
        cout << "A bar was destroyed!" << endl;

    }
```

When a bar is created, i want the given values T and S to be assigned immediately to the foo object-member.At the marked lines i tried to overwrite these values but none of these seems to work and i get the error: "default argument for parameter of type foo has type 'int'".How can i get this to work?

Comment: `bar(int x, int y, foo n=(0,0)` => `bar(int x, int y, foo n= foo(0,0)`

Comment: That works, but  i want the mutator methods below to get the values to it too.

Comment: Another option is: `foo n{0,0}`

Comment: True, but how can the foo created inside the bar get the values from the bar class? ( using the mutators i marked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
bar(int x, int y, foo n=foo(0,0)) : ... { ... }
```

If you are able to use a C++11 compiler, you can also use:

```
bar(int x, int y, foo n=foo{0,0}) : ... { ... }
```

and

```
bar(int x, int y, foo n={0,0}) : ... { ... }
```

Instead of:

```
    foo.set_a(T);
    foo.set_b(S);
```

you need to use:

```
    f.set_a(T);
    f.set_b(S);
```

since you need to call `set_a` and `set_b` on the member variable `f`.

---

A better alternative is to initialize `f` using:

```
bar(int x, int y} : T(x), S(y), f(x, y) {}
```

and leave the body of the constructor empty.